# How can I mount SMB drive as folder with chmod 777?

Tags: networking, mount, kubuntu, samba

I am trying to use Freefilesync to sync my local HDD with a Samba shared NAS. When connecting directly in Konqueror like smb:// etc. I am able to read and write without problem but I need to mount is as folder to make Freefilesync to see it.

I am able to mount it this way (I replaced the IP with nines to not publish it here)::

```
juhele@Latitude:~/Dokumenty$ sudo mount -t cifs //999.999.99.99/Public /media/jan_helebrant/QNAP_NAS -o user=juhele
Password for juhele@//999.999.99.99/Public:
juhele@Latitude:~/Dokumenty$
```

But this does not
Tried chmod 777 before mounting but after mounting it changes to chmod 755. I assume this is because I have to mount as root but I have no idea how to give my user account privileges to moun this particular drive as it is not listed in /etc/fstab and I do not see it in Gparted of course so I cannot use the tutorials I found.

any idea?

thanks

Comment: See the `file_mode` and `dir_mode` mount options.

Comment: ok thanks, will check it. Strange that I did not find that question before posting mine :-)